# Converting gui py file to exe takes much time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I developed a python gui app that uses Tkinter and build the gui from config file.
the script itself compiles in a second in a python compiler(vs-code).
I used pyinstaller --onefile option to convert the python to exe and it works, but takes about
20 seconds to work.
I need a standalone app(not a directory).
Is there a better way to compile py to exe to work fine?

Comment: I seem to recall (at least for one exe-compiler we tested, not sure which) the "one file" option needs to unpack to a temp directory every time you run it. This is likely to be causing a start up delay if it's the case with your exe-compiler.

Comment: Obviously thats the cause, without the --onefile parameter it works quite good.
Anyways, I'm looking for a better solution?